# jclouds newbie-- unable to download any JClouds JAR files with lein

Tags: clojure, leiningen, jclouds

As per instructions at Jclouds website, I downloaded the Lein BAT file, and also downloaded Curl to the same folder. I am working on a Windows 8 x64 PC.

Now I created a file named "project.clj" within the folder containing lein and curl.

After that, I ran the following command--

```
lein deps
```

However, all this does is create a file within following path (within the folder containing Lein and curl)--

```
target\scale\dependencies
```

The file named "dependencies" contains the following text--

```
  ([:dependencies [[org.jclouds/jclouds-all "1.5.3"] [org.jclouds.driver/jclouds-sshj "1.5.3"]]])
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here... How do I download all of the jclouds files correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry, this was updated with lein 2.  jclouds.apache.org [doc](http://jclouds.apache.org/start/install/#lein) is now corrected.

After creating project.clj...

```
Execute lein pom, then mvn dependency:copy-dependencies which will fill target/dependency with all the jclouds jars.
```